# asp.net mvc 3 Dropdown list with compound display member?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have inherited a half completed MVC project which is to keep track of licenses for our customers' products.

There are two dropdown lists on the license Create.cshtml page, the first of which allows you to choose a customer and the second of which then populates the products that customer owns (CustomerProducts) to allow you to select which CustomerProduct you wish to create a license for, as follows:

```
<div class="editor-label">Customer</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Customers, "Id", "Name"), "-- Select Customer --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCustomerId)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">Product</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCustomerProductId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Select Product --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCustomerProductId)
</div>
```

The problem I'm running into is that CustomerProducts are associated with both a Product *and* a Version but the dropdown is only displaying the Product name, not the Version name so if the customer owns both "Productname v1.0" and "Productname v1.1" the dropdown only shows Productname twice. So what I'd be looking for is something like (pseudocode):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCustomerProductId + " (" + model.SelectedCustomerProductId.ProductVersion.Name + ")", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Select Product --")
```

I'm sure there must be a simple way to get that dropdown to display both the Product and the Version but I have scoured and scoured every source I can think of and haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Apologies if this is an elementary question; I'm new to MVC and have spent a couple of days searching for a solution to what seems to me should be a very simple issue!

**Edit:**

Following up on @von v.'s suggestion below, added a read only property to CustomerProduct:

```
public virtual string ProductVersionFullName { get { return Product.Name + " (" + ProductVersion.Name + ")"; } }
```

It's then just a case of using that property as the display member rather that trying to bind to multiple properties of the CustomerProduct in the dropdown (the dropdown is populated by a method in LicensesController which is where the display member is set). I knew I was missing something simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of the `DropDownListFor` is defined as

> An expression that identifies the object that contains the properties
>   to display

If you are looking into that, that can get you confused. But basically the first argument is the expression that "points to" the property of your model where you want the value of the dropdown to be bound to. In your case your model has a property `SelectedCustomerProductId` and that is where the **selected value** of the dropdown will be "put into". That should be a single property. If you want to show more text into the dropdown list then you need to build that into the selectlistitem.

So in your controller method you will have something like:

```
// this is where you build your model
var model =initializeYourModel();

// this is where you build the Products
// whose values are used in the DropDownList.
// I assume you already have the code that builds the list,
// this is just an example that shows 
// where you should build the "Product and the Version"
model.Products = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{ Value = "1", Text = "the name " + "the version"},
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I *think* this is enough to get me moving again. I'll post code when I have a working solution.

Comment: Glad to help and get you going.

Comment: Yep cracked it, obvious once you've been pointed in the right direction! Have edited my question to include solution. Thanks again.